# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input in react/express

Tags: reactjs, express, sequelize.js

Scratching my head like crazy, my "POST" route works just fine and the same exact code for my "PUT" route is returning a `"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"` in the browser. It WILL update, but its not going thru the .then() parts of my fetch request, and going right to the catch block.

Fetch on my react app:

```
   const updateCourse = async(e) => { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
         const encodedCreds = btoa(
             `${props.creds.emailAddress}:${props.creds.password}`
           );
        
    await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/courses/' + params.id, {
         method: 'PUT', 
         headers : {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
             Authorization: `Basic ${encodedCreds}`,
         }, 
         body: JSON.stringify(course)
     }).then(res =>  res.json())
     .then((data) => {
         if(data.message) {
           setErrorMessage(data.message.errors)
         }else{
             nav('/course/' + data)
         }
        })
     
     .catch((err) => {
         console.log('error message', err)
     });
```

API response in express:

```
    router.put("/api/courses/:id", authUser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const findCourse = await courses.findOne({
      where: {
        id: req.params.id,
      },
    });

    if (findCourse) {
      //----IF ITS A VALID COURSE--//
      const updateCourse = await findCourse.update(req.body);
      res.status(204);
      res.json(updateCourse.id)
      
      
    } else {
      res.json({
        message: "Could not find course",
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({
      message: err
    });
    
  }
});
```

find the full code here : https://github.com/ccarver80/React-REST-FS-API

Answer (score 1):

The variable you are passing to JSON.stringify(course) is not defined.

Comment: course is defined, I just didn't include all of my code to narrow down where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I didn't realize my API was sending back a 204 status which is "No content" so my client wasn't seeing any JSON to process technically.

A simple "IF/ELSE" statement in my client fixed this issue,

```
 .then((res) => {
         if(res.status === 204) {
             nav('/course/' + params.id)
         }else {
            return res.json()
         }
     })
```